# list-style: none; in css file wont remove bullet points from list

Tags: html, css, list

I am trying to remove the bullet points from a list using a style.css file linked to an HTML base file that is calling on a navbar. html file but list-style: none; doesn't remove them?

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Easy News</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text\css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
    <label class="logo">Design</label>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Servives</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
    </ul> 
</nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am guessing the browser probably refuses to _apply_ your stylesheet, because of the _invalid_ type you specified. `type="text/css"` would be correct.

Comment: Try to add ```!important``` to override the default style. If it does not work, I recommend these two, ```ul{ list-style: none }``` or ```li { list-style: none }```